# How to render icon based on props using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using [react-feather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-feather) to render icons in a component. I'm able to get it to import a static icon by hard coding it in. But how do I make it render the icon based on what has been passed to it in the `IconLeft.icon` props?

```
import { Camera } from 'react-feather';
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

type HeaderProps = {
    title: string;
    iconLeft?: {
        icon?: string;
        url?: string;
        state?: string;
        label?: string;
    }
}

export const DefaultHeader: FunctionComponent<HeaderProps> = ({ title, iconLeft, iconRight}) => <header>
    <h1>{String}</h1>
    <Camera size={24} stroke-width={2}/>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cloneElement` to dynamically render any component you want by passing it as a prop.

```
import React, { cloneElement, FunctionComponent } from "react";

type HeaderProps = {
    title: string;
    iconLeft?: {
        icon: JSX.Element;
        url?: string;
        state?: string;
        label?: string;
    };
};

export const DefaultHeader: FunctionComponent<HeaderProps> = ({
    title,
    iconLeft,
}) => (
    <header>
        <h1>{String}</h1>
        {iconLeft && cloneElement(iconLeft.icon, { size: 24, "stroke-width": 2 })}
    </header>
);
```

Usage example:

```
<DefaultHeader iconLeft={{ icon: <Camera /> }} />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `JSX.Element` as the type for icon props.

Example:

```
type HeaderProps = {
  title: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
};

const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = ({ icon, title }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {icon}
    </header>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="header" icon={<Camera />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit throbbing-voice-1uv84w]